# Как сделать JPopupMenu невидимым?

Tags: java, swing

Не получается отключать JPopupMenu методами setVisible() и setEnabled(). Отдельные JMenuItem без проблем обрабатываются этими методами, а вот меню целиком никак на них не реагирует. Как можно сделать, чтобы контекстное меню появлялось по правому клику только когда нужно? Какой метод способен включать и отключать его целиком?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PopupMenus extends JFrame {
    public PopupMenus() {
        super("PopupMenus");
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        JPopupMenu popup = createPopupMenu();
        ((JComponent)getContentPane()).
                setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        setSize(300, 200);
        popup.setVisible(false); // Эти строки можно удалить.
        popup.setEnabled(false); // Они не влияют ни на что.
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private JPopupMenu createPopupMenu() {
        JPopupMenu pm = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem good = new JMenuItem("Один");
        JMenuItem excellent = new JMenuItem("Два");
        pm.add(good);
        pm.add(excellent);
        return pm;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                PopupMenus::new);
    }
}
```

Строки

```
popup.setVisible(false);
popup.setEnabled(false);
```

не влияют на появление контекстного меню. Оно появляется при клике правой кнопкой мыши в любом случае.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы была возможность отключать и включать возможность показа всего контекстного меню?

Comment: Приведите проблемный участок кода

Comment: Роман, я добавила код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросал решеньице. Просто надо `setComponentPopupMenu(null)` сделать.

```java
boolean showed = true;

PopupMenus() {
    super("PopupMenus");
    setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    JPopupMenu popup = createPopupMenu();
    ((JComponent)getContentPane()).setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
    setSize(300, 200);

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();

    add(jPanel);

    JButton jButton = new JButton("Button");

    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (showed) {
                ((JComponent)getContentPane()).setComponentPopupMenu(null);
                showed = false;
            } else {
                ((JComponent)getContentPane()).setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
                showed = true;
            }
        }
    });

    // Или более коротко
    // jButton.addActionListener(e -> ((JComponent)getContentPane()).setComponentPopupMenu((showed = !showed) ? popup : null));

    jPanel.add(jButton);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Во!! То, что нужно! Классное решение! Большое спасибо!